# Find $E$($\hatβ$) and var($\hatβ$) in simple linear regression model $Yi=α+βXi+μi$ for $i = 1, ..., n$

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, econometrics, least-squares

Consider the following simple linear model
[image]

Comment: The title does not match your question, as $\hat\beta$ is OLS in your question, but you are interested in another estimator. Also, please add the self-study tag (to do so, remove mean, it is not needed here). Further, screenshots are not very popular here, as the site cannot search images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you how to solve the first part $E(\tilde\beta)$. Then you may try other parts.

$$E(\tilde\beta)=E(\frac{\bar{y_2}-\bar{y_1}}{\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}})=E(\frac{\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^{n}y_{i}-\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}y_{i}}{\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^{n}x_{i}-\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}x_{i}})$$

Now we can concel $\frac{2}{n}$ and substitute $y_i=\alpha+\beta x_i+\mu_i$

we get

$$E(\tilde\beta)=E(\frac{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^{n}(\alpha+\beta x_i+\mu_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(\alpha+\beta x_i+\mu_i)}{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^{n}x_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}x_{i}})=E(\frac{\frac{n}{2}\alpha+\beta \sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^nx_i+0-\frac{n}{2}\alpha-\beta \sum_{1}^{n/2}x_i-0}{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^nx_i-\sum_{i}^{n}x_i})=E(\beta\frac{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^nx_i-\sum_{i}^{n}x_i}{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^nx_i-\sum_{i}^{n}x_i})=E(\beta*1)=\beta$$

Note $E(\mu_i)=0$

$\therefore \tilde \beta$ is an unbiased estimation of $\beta$

Comment: Thanks @deep north for the guideline am guessing for $Var(\tilde\beta)$ goes just the same way

Answer (score 0):

I guess for $Var(\tilde\beta)$ goes the same way but not sure if $Var(\hat\beta)$ will just be the same hence  $Var(\tilde\beta)$ == $Var(\hat\beta)$.

$$Var(\tilde\beta)=Var(\frac{\bar{y_2}-\bar{y_1}}{\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}})=Var(\frac{\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^{n}y_{i}-\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}y_{i}}{\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^{n}x_{i}-\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}x_{i}})$$

Cancel $\frac{2}{n}$ and substitute $y_i=\alpha+\beta x_i+\mu_i$

$$Var(\tilde\beta)=Var(\frac{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^{n}(\alpha+\beta x_i+\mu_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(\alpha+\beta x_i+\mu_i)}{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^{n}x_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}x_{i}})=Var(\frac{\frac{n}{2}\alpha+\beta \sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^nx_i+\mu_i-\frac{n}{2}\alpha-\beta \sum_{1}^{n/2}x_i-\mu_i}{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^nx_i-\sum_{i}^{n}x_i})=Var(\beta\frac{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^nx_i-\sum_{i}^{n}x_i}{\sum_{i=(n/2)+1}^nx_i-\sum_{i}^{n}x_i})=Var(\beta*1)=\beta$$

EDIT

\begin{align}
{\rm Var} (\hat{\beta})
  &= \frac{ 1 }{ \left[\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2 \right]^2 }
    \sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2 {\rm Var} (Y_i) \\
  &= \frac{ \sigma^2 }{ \sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2  } ,
\end{align}

Comment: Nope you mere to think about how the variance operator work. Further without doing any math you should be able to figure why the variance of the new estimator can never be smaller than OLS (given the assumptions stated in the question)

Comment: Ok, check the edit if am on the right track.

Comment: How should I compare the variance of the new estimator can never be smaller than OLS

Comment: Look up the Gauss Markov theorem in your book

Comment: ok, Is that edit I did correct for $Var(\hat\beta)$?